# Trying to figure out cleaner way to compare two arrays of objects and add properties for each match

Tags: javascript

I have two separate arrays of objects coming back as a data response. I'm currently comparing the two arrays for all items with matching IDs and taking the properties from items in array2 and adding them to the matching item in array1.

Right now I'm using a nested `for` loop to accomplish this but I hate using nested loops and I'm trying to figure out if there's a cleaner way to write this.

As of now this is my function and a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vigilant-bas-o42v4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark):

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
  for (var k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++) {
    if (arr2[i].id === arr1[k].id) {
      arr1[k].group = arr2[i].group;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matchMerge(array1, array2, key)`

Parameters:

1. `array1` Array of objects
2. `array2` Array of objects
3. `key` String of the key to match

Function will:

1. extract all values of the given `key` from `array2` with `.map()`

```
let arr2Key = array2.map(obj2 => obj2[key]);
```

2. finds any match of it's `key` value vs. `arr2Key` values and gets an index or -1.

```
 let idx = arr2Key.indexOf(obj1[key]);
```

3. if `idx` is greater than -1 then return a merged object using the spread operator `...` from both arrays otherwise return the object from `array1`

```
return idx > -1 ? { ...obj1, ...array2[idx]} : obj1
```

***Note:*** This function will accept any 2 array of objects and any key/property to match. It keeps the content of the first array and only adds whatever it doesn't have from the matching objects of the second array.

```js
const arr1=[{name:"A Quiet Place",id:"123"},{name:"Sweet Tooth",id:"456"},{name:"I Love You, Man",id:"789"}],arr2=[{group:"Horror",id:"123"},{group:"Fantasy",id:"456"},{group:"Comedy",id:"789"},{group:"Everything else",id:"001"}];

const cloner = (...arrayOfArrays) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayOfArrays));

const matchMerge = (array1, array2, key) => {
  let arr2Key = array2.map(obj2 => obj2[key]);

  return array1.map(obj1 => {
    let idx = arr2Key.indexOf(obj1[key]);
    return idx > -1 ? { ...obj1, ...array2[idx]} : obj1
  });
}

let AA = cloner(arr1, arr2);

console.log(matchMerge(AA[0], AA[1], 'id'));

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: I think it might be better to avoid mutating the source array by returning a new array with shallow clones.

Comment: @Tom good point, added a helper function.

Answer (score 0):

Turn one of them into an object or Map indexed by `id`, then iterate through the other, `O(n)`.

```
const objs1ById = Object.fromEntries(
  arr1.map(obj => [obj.id, obj])
);
for (const obj2 of arr2) {
  const obj1 = objs1ById[obj2.id];
  if (obj1) obj1.group = obj2.group;
}
```